# How to make time input easy on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

So, making my problem simple, I have two columns on excel.

The first one (A) should be a time input formatted as `hh:mm`.

The second one (B) should be a time input formatted as `hh:mm:ss`.

Ok, so as I am making it easier to the end-user. I would like to help him and make it work in a way he can easily type `"1230"` in column A so it would be automatically converted to `12:30`, and easily type `"153055"` in column B so it would be automatically converted to `15:30:55`.

So basically I want to save him from typing colons.

Thus, I've created this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim vVala, vValb

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B100")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub



     With Target



         vVala = Format(.Value, "000000")
         vValb = Format(.Value, "0000")

          If IsNumeric(vVala) And Len(vVala) = 6 Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            .Value = Left(vVala, 2) & ":" & Mid(vVala, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(vVala, 2)

            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

          End If

          If IsNumeric(vValb) And Len(vValb) = 4 Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            .Value = Left(vValb, 2) & ":" & Right(vValb, 2)

            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

          End If



    End With




     Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

The problem is that I am getting a bug. When I type, for example, in any column B cell, `011003`it correctly gives me `01:10:03`, but if the hours equal zero, e.g. `000103` (or `00:01:03`) it doesn't actually understand the zeros to be the hours, and gives me `01:03`.

This is likely caused due to the fact that the range of my target is set to both columns `(Range("A1:B100"))`, when it should be separate: the "4 digit" code to the column A, and the "6 digit" code to the column B.

I don't know how to separate targets, though. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, if `1234` is typed

- in Column `A`, you want it interpreted as `12:34:00`
  (but formatted as `hh:mm` → `12:34`).
- in Column `B`, you want it interpreted as `00:12:34`
  (formatted as `hh:mm:ss`).

So there’s no way the routine can figure out what to do
just by looking at the input data (as your attempt, and my previous one, did);
it has to know what column the user is typing in. 
The way to do that is to check `Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100"))`
and `Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B100"))`,
and then just use the appropriate format for the column you’re in, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim vVal

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B100")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
            ' We’re in Column A, so use hh:mm.
            vVal = Format(.Value, "0000")

            If IsNumeric(vVal) And Len(vVal) = 4 Then
                .Value = Left(vVal, 2) & ":" & Right(vVal, 2)
                .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
            End If
        Else
            ' We’re in Column B, so use hh:mm:ss.
            vVal = Format(.Value, "000000")

            If IsNumeric(vVal) And Len(vVal) = 6 Then
                .Value = Left(vVal, 2) & ":" & Mid(vVal, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(vVal, 2)
                .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It turns out that,
once we’ve confirmed that the target is in Column `A` or `B`,
and then we check whether it’s in Column `A`,
then we don’t need to explicitly test whether it’s in Column `B`
— that’s the only place it can be. 
And, since we always know what format to use, we need only one `vVal` variable.

And, unlike my previous attempt to answer,
I have tested this, and it seems to work. 
(I spent only a few minutes testing,
so there could be subtle bugs yet to be discovered.)

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to do the step three. I can't manage to make it. This is how it looks after steps 1 and 2: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIR83

Comment: Can you please send me how it should look after step 3? igorradichi@gmail.com

Comment: I owe you multiple apologies.  (1) The first two bullet points in my original answer were wrong.  I don’t know what I was thinking.  (2) I meant to get back to you much sooner than this.  I didn’t forget about you, but I got distracted. … … … … … … … … (3) BTW, we discourage direct email contact between members.  [SU] is part of [SE], and it is [SE]’s goal to build a knowledge repository that people can use in the future.  (Google search results often point to [SE] or [SU].)  If I sent information to you individually, then how would anybody else get to use it?  (4) Anyway, I updated my answer.